# talend take out zeros before the comma

Tags: etl, talend

I have a file with two columns the first one with a name and the second one with a number.

The size of the number column is 20 chars, the numbers use to be less than 2 chars size the rest of the chars are complite with 0.

I need to take out all the zeros before the comma. I should use a tMap, How?

Comment: Is talend the language your using? If not, could you specify? I've never heard of talend before.

Comment: Is not a language, is a ETL Software Talend Open Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:
Using a tMap, put a Var in the midle of both files (Input and output).
In the var use:

```
"0"+row1.numberField.split(",")[0].replace("0", "") + "." + row1.numberField.split(",")[1]
```

Example:
000000001,58
Result:
01.58

Solution 2:
Define your own routine:

```
public static String calcImp(String theNumber) {
    Float theFNumber = new Float(theNumber.replace(",", "."));

    return Float.toString(theFNumber).replace(".", ",");
}
```

Example:
000000001,587
Result:
1,587